# Получение данных из другой БД Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

Стоит такая задача - получить в одной БД (`DB1`) данные таблицы из другой БД (`DB2`) и сравнить их. Так как `Azure` не поддерживает кросс-запросы между базами, иду через `EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteDS WITH   
    (TYPE = RDBMS,   
    LOCATION = '<path>.database.windows.net',   
    DATABASE_NAME = 'DB2',   
    CREDENTIAL = SQL_Credential --объявлен выше 
) ;   


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = RemoteDS 
);
```

Насколько я правильно понимаю, в имени `EXTERNAL TABLE` нужно указывать имя таблицы в DB2, однако в DB1 уже есть таблица с точно таким же названием (с ней и нужно сравнивать). Соответственно создать объект с таким же именем невозможно.

Есть ли какой-то обход ситуации с именами или другие способы сравнить две таблицы с одинаковыми именами в разных базах данных?

Comment: Попробуйте создать таблицу с другим именем, указав опцию *OBJECT_NAME*: `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[DB2_Employee] (...) WITH (DATA_SOURCE = RemoteDS, OBJECT_NAME = N'Employee');`, ну или создать внешнюю таблицу в другой схеме.

Comment: @i-one с `OBJECT_NAME` все отработало (дополнительно добавила опцию `SCHEMA_NAME`), благодарю